# Gif completion listener in flutter

Tags: flutter, listener, gif, animated-gif

I am using Image.asset() to load and play GIF and I need to perform certain action when the GIF has completed playing.

So, is there any way to know when GIF has completed playing in flutter? Or can there be any listener for the same?

Comment: Instead use `Lottie` it has more properties and much faster than Gif and it renders natively

Answer (score 0):

There is no Gif completion listener in flutter.

we have to handle with time.
[Try this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/gif_view

It has `onFinish` property. You can also load GIF from Assets.

Example:

```
class InitializationPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const InitializationPage({super.key});

  static const route = '/init';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = GifController(
      loop: false,
      onFinish: () {},
    );

    return GifView.asset(
      'assets/gif/example.gif',
      controller: controller,
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    );
  }
}
```