# Flutter how to know if GIF done animated without looping

Tags: flutter, dart, gif

How to know if GIF done playing? I want to build another widget and call a function but after the GIF done animated once. Is there anyway to achieve this?

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
    child: const Image(
      image: AssetImage(
        "images/splas_screen.GIF",
      ),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is currently how I display the GIF because I still have no idea how to play the GIF only once without looping and call a function after.

Comment: if there's no specific callback you can count the frames of animation and calculate the timeout on your own? So when the timeout is up you could trigger the second widget

Comment: could you include your code?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/frameBuilder.html

Comment: @eamirho3ein updated my post, my code for displaying the gif is as simple as that because have no idea how to do what I asked

Comment: @AlbertoCappellina I was going to do that, but I'm afraid that when a device is using the apps and the device is laggy, might affect the gif animation to be slower than the timeout I set causing timeout before animation is completed.

Comment: @eskemender if you can you should try https://pub.dev/packages/lottie . the only difficult part is to convert gif to json definition. give it a try! that shourely has a "end animation" callback

Comment: @pskink I tried it, still looping, the condition where wasSynchronouslyLoaded is true was not called. Even after I put condition where frame equals to a specific frame, the widget inside that condition is called but disappear almost instantly and the GIF continued looping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flutter_gif](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gif) and set `repeat` property to `ImageRepeat.noRepeat`, like this:

```
GifImage(image:AssetImage("images/splas_screen.GIF"), controller: controller,repeat:ImageRepeat.noRepeat ),
```

This is a full example of what you need:

```
class TestAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestAnimation({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestAnimation> createState() => _TestAnimationState();
}

class _TestAnimationState extends State<TestAnimation>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late FlutterGifController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = FlutterGifController(vsync: this);
    controller.animateTo(10, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)); // Note that animate to your last frame of your animation, here mine is 10.
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.isCompleted) {
        print("compleate");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Testing")),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          GifImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/Pivot_Wave.gif"),
            controller: controller,
            repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, finally got what I need. Worked great, for now I will use this but still gonna try another method because the package seems not updated for a long time, might be depreciated later.

Comment: Glad to heat that, I don't think it depreciate in future, the last Update was 5 month ago, and it is good.

Answer (score 0):

try using this package

flutter_gif: ^0.0.4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77314988/18102423

If you use [GifView](https://pub.dev/packages/gif_view) it has `onFinish` property.